# Receiving done notifications from observables built using switch

Tags: rxjs

In the below example, `foo` receives data from `bar` yet ignores when `bar` completes. `foo` is completed when `baz` completes, which is not the behavior I desire.

```
var baz = Rx.Observable.interval( 50 ).take( 10 );

var foo = baz
    .select(function (x) { 
        var bar = Rx.Observable.range(x, 3);
        return bar;
    })
    .switch();
```

Is there a variant of `switch` or a technique that I could use to have the newly created `foo` observable have the same lifetime as `bar`? That is, I would like `foo` to complete in the event that `bar` completes.

---

Solution:

```
var baz = Rx.Observable.interval( 50 ).take( 10 );

var foo = baz
    .select(function (x) { 
        var bar = Rx.Observable.range(x, 3).materialize()
        return bar;
    })
    .switch()
    .dematerialize();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onCompleted()` is by definition a terminal case so no you cannot receive `onCompleted()` directly in the outer `Observable`.

You have a couple options depending on how you need to use the `onCompleted`.

Either you could use `.tapOnCompleted()` or `.finally()` to handle a side effect of stream termination:

```
var foo = Rx.Observable.range(0, 3)
.select(function (x) { 
    return Rx.Observable.range(x, 3)
           .tapOnCompleted(function(){/*Apply side effect*/});
          //Or .finally()

})
.switch();
```

Or you will need to `materialize` the inner stream to handle the values:

```
var foo = Rx.Observable.range(0, 3)
.select(function (x) { 
    var bar = Rx.Observable.range(x, 3)
    .materialize();
    return bar;
})

.switch()

foo.subscribe(function(x) {
  if (x.kind == 'N') {
    process(x.value);
  } else if (x.kind == 'C') { /*Do something else*/}
});
```

Note that in the example you gave when the `switch` occurs the `Observable` will not complete, only the last one will complete, because subsequent values are coming in too fast.

If all of the sequences should be running until completed you should use `concatAll()` instead of `switch()`

Comment: I'm modified the example so hopefully it's a bit more clear. I'm really surprised there is no operator for what I want to achieve. RxJS doesn't have materialize, or that would work.