# RxJs - parse file, group lines by topics, but I miss the end

Tags: rxjs

I am trying RxJS.

My use case is to parse a log file and group lines by topic ( i.e.: the beginning of the group is the filename and then after that I have some lines with user, date/time and so on) 
 I can analyse the lines using regExp. I can determine the beginning of the group.

I use ".scan" to group the lines together, when I've the beginning of new group of line, I create an observer on the lines I've accumulated ... fine.

The issue is the end of the file. I've started a new group, I am accumulating lines but I can not trigger the last sequence as I do not have the information that the end. I would have expect to have the information in the complete (but not)

Here is an example using number. Begin of group can multi of 3 or 5. (remark: I work in typescript)

```js
import * as Rx from "rx";

let r = Rx.Observable
        .range(0, 8)
        .scan( function(acc: number[], value: number): number[]{
            if (( value % 3 === 0) || ( value % 5 === 0)) {
                acc.push(value);
                let info = acc.join(".");
                Rx.Observable
                    .fromArray(acc)
                    .subscribe( (value) => {
                        console.log(info, "=>", value);
                    });
                acc = [];
            } else {
                acc.push(value);
            }
            return acc;
        }, [])
        .subscribe( function (x) {
            // console.log(x);
        });
```

This emit:

```
 0 => 0
 1.2.3 => 1
 1.2.3 => 2
 1.2.3 => 3
 4.5 => 4
 4.5 => 5
 6 => 6
```

I am looking how to emit

```
 0 => 0
 1.2.3 => 1
 1.2.3 => 2
 1.2.3 => 3
 4.5 => 4
 4.5 => 5
 6 => 6
 7.8 => 7     last items are missing as I do not know how to detect end
 7.8 => 8
```

Can you help me, grouping items?
 Any good idea, even not using scan, is welcome.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `materialize` operator. See the documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/materialize-dematerialize.html) and the [marbles](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/materialize.md) here, and an [example of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999682/receiving-done-notifications-from-observables-built-using-switch) from SO.

In your case, I would try something like (untested but hopefully you can complete it yourself, note that I don't know a thing about typescript so there might be some syntax errors):

import * as Rx from "rx";

```
let r = Rx.Observable
        .range(0, 8)
        .materialize()
        .scan( function(acc: number[], materializedNumber: Rx.Notification<number>): number[]{
            let rangeValue: number = materializedNumber.value;

            if (( rangeValue % 3 === 0) || ( rangeValue % 5 === 0)) {
                acc.push(rangeValue);
                generateNewObserverOnGroupOf(acc);
                acc = [];
            } else if ( materializedNumber.kind === "C") {
                generateNewObserverOnGroupOf(acc);
                acc = [];
            } else {
                acc.push(rangeValue);
            }
            return acc;
        }, [])
        // .dematerialize()
        .subscribe( function (x) {
            // console.log(x);
        });

function generateNewObserverOnGroupOf(acc: number[]) {
    let info = acc.join(".");
                Rx.Observable
                    .fromArray(acc)
                    .subscribe( (value) => {
                        console.log(info, "=>", value);
                    });
```

The idea is that the `materialize` and `dematerialize` works with notifications, which encodes whether the message being passed by the stream is one of `next`, `error`, `completed` kinds (respectively 'N', 'E', 'C' values for the `kind` property). If you have a `next` notification, then the value passed is in the `value` field of the notification object. Note that you need to dematerialize to return to the normal behaviour of the stream so it can complete and free resources when finished.