# What's the use case of Notification in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm somewhat familiar with basic RxJS concepts like Observables, Observers and Subjects but [RxJS Notifications](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Notification) concept is completely new to me.

What is it for? When should I use it?

Answer (score 6):

The documentation you quoted mentions :

> This class is particularly useful for operators that manage notifications, like `materialize`, `dematerialize`, `observeOn`, and others. Besides wrapping the actual delivered value, it also annotates it with metadata of, for instance, what type of push message it is (`next`, `error`, or `complete`).

So the question turns out to be about use cases for `materialize` and the like.

Basically, you use `materialize` to get meta-information about the dataflow without incurring into the associated side-effects (an error incurring in a stream for example propagates, a stream which completes can lead to the completion of other streams etc.). `dematerialize` allows to restore the side-effects.

Here are uses case from former SO questions :

- [Receiving done notifications from observables built using switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999682/receiving-done-notifications-from-observables-built-using-switch)
- [RxJs - parse file, group lines by topics, but I miss the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295133/rxjs-parse-file-group-lines-by-topics-but-i-miss-the-end/36297126#36297126)

Answer (score 2):

A use case: as errors or completions are propagated immediately, you can't for example delay them. To do so, you can try this approach:

```
// sample stream
interval(500).pipe(
  mapTo('normal value'),
  // sometimes value, sometimes throw
  map(v => {
    if (randomInt() > 50) {
     throw new Error('boom!')
    } else return v;
   }),
  materialize(),
  // turns Observable<T> into Notification<Observable<T>>
  // so we can delay or what you want
  delay(500),
  // and we need to do some magic and change Notification of error into
  // Notification of value (error message)
  map(n => n.hasValue? n : new Notification('N', n.error.message, null)),
  // back to normal
  dematerialize()
)
// now it never throw so in console we will have 
// `normal value` or `boom!` but all as... normal values (next() emmision)
// and delay() works as expected
.subscribe(v => console.log(v))
```